# Trying To Get Categories Per Entry ID

Tags: categories, channel-entries-api, api

I'm doing headless coding. I have been using the `?ACT=40` API to get entries, doing something like: `?ACT=40&url_title=my-entry-slug` to get JSON of a single article. However, it doesn't list for me the categories. So, I asked ChatGPT to help. After it giving me stale docs and told it that I couldn't load the EE bootstrap properly, it finally got me to code like the following, but it has a bug in that it says: `Unable to locate the specified class: Benchmark.php` How do I overcome my bug so that I can take an entry_id of an entry and find its list of related categories? Note, I saved the file as getcats.php in the root of the CMS directory and then called it with `https://example.com/getcats.php?entry_id=23` where 23 was a valid entry ID in my case.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
$entry_id= @ $_GET['entry_id'];
define('EE_PATH', '/system/ee/');
define('EE_BOOTPATH', '/system/ee/ExpressionEngine/Boot/');
$system_path = './system';
$debug = 1;
$routing['directory'] = '';
$routing['controller'] = 'ee';
$routing['function'] = 'index';
if (realpath($system_path) !== false) {
    $system_path = realpath($system_path);
}
$system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/') . '/';
define('SELF', basename(__FILE__));
define('EESELF', basename(__FILE__));
define('FCPATH', __DIR__ . '/');
define('SYSPATH', $system_path);
define('BASEPATH', $system_path);
define('SYSDIR', basename($system_path));
define('DEBUG', $debug);  unset($debug); 
$config['user_config_path'] = SYSPATH . 'user/config/config.php';
require_once $config['user_config_path'];
require_once SYSPATH . 'ee/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.php';
ee()->load->library('api');
ee()->legacy_api->instantiate('channel_entries');
$categories = ee()->api_channel_entries->get_categories($entry_id);
print_r($categories);
```

Comment: Holy wow that's the hard way to go about things... have you taken a look at Bone? https://expressionengine.com/add-ons/bones

Comment: Yes, I have paid for and installed Bones, but found the /api calls were failing, but could get the ACT calls to work. However, the ACT calls allow me to get entries and channels data, but not a list of categories per entry. For now, I use the ACT calls to iterate a list of channel IDs with `?ACT=40&url_title=$sSlug&category=$nCatID` until I get a hit. However, that's pretty taxing on the system and kind of convoluted in my opinion. It's like, "iterate some categories until you find a match for this article ID", rather than "here's an article ID, now show the categories it is assigned".